# Boolean switch from 1/0 to 0/1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I quite often use a formula like:

```
=1*(A2=G2)
```

If A2 and G2 are the same then it returns `1` - otherwise it returns `0`.

I realise it is trivial with an `IF` function but I'm *specifically* interested in this format of function using `1*`.

How can I amend it so that if A2 and G2 are NOT the same it returns `1`, otherwise `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `<>` operator to check inequality:

```
=1*(A2<>G2)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just subtract the result from 1, to invert it

```
=1-1*(A2=G2)
```

Comment: If you're already doing math, you don't need the `1*`, i.e. `=1-(A2=G2)`

Answer (score 3):

Sticking a Not formula in there seems to work - like this

```
=1*(NOT(A3=A3))
```

Comment: You might have typo'ed `A3=A3` and the second set of brackets around the `Not` is unnecessary.

Comment: A3=a3 was just to make sure that matching=0, I also had a3=a4 which =1. Good to know that I don't need to use an extra bracket set :)